# Connect between ComboBox and TextBox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have `ComboBox`  that gets his values from db and empty `Textbox` that gets no value.
I want that when i change the value in the `ComboBox` the value in the `TextBox` will change also with the value of the same row in the db for example:

```
--------------------------
| name | price | details |
--------------------------
|bob  f|    12 |   admin |
```

so when i choose in the `ComboBox` "bob f" the `TextBox` will show "12".

```
 private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DbCards d = new DbCards();
     DataTable dr = d.GetQuery("SELECT * from Cards").Tables[0];
 }
```

thanks.

Comment: what kind of application is this? asp.net or winforms

Comment: windows form application @un-lucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is, Bind the ComboBox using a DataTable with `name` as its `DisplayMember` and `price` as its `ValueMember`. So that The corresponding value can be taken up on selection changes. Let `BindingSoure` be a datatable which is populated from the database;

Binding will be:

```
BindingSoure= d.GetQuery("SELECT name,price from Cards").Tables[0]
comboBox2.DataSource = BindingSoure;
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBox2.ValueMember = "price";
```

Let `txtPrice` be the textBox in which you wanted to show the Price as well. so the code for that will be:

```
 txtPrice.Text = comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DbCards d = new DbCards();
    DataTable dr = d.GetQuery("SELECT * from Cards").Tables[0];
    comboBox1.DataSource = dr;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "price";
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Form1()
{
    //InitializeComponent();

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("a");
    dt.Columns.Add("b");
    dt.Rows.Add("a1", "b1");
    dt.Rows.Add("a2", "b2");
    dt.Rows.Add("a3", "b3");

    var dgv = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
    dgv.DataSource = dt;

    var tb = new TextBox { Parent = this, Top = dgv.Bottom };
    tb.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "a");

    var cb = new ComboBox { Parent = this, Top = tb.Top, Left = tb.Right + 20 };
    cb.DisplayMember = "a";
    cb.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Use full power of data bindings.